# JMeter - Sent GET request with square brackets on path

Tags: jmeter

I need to make an HTTP GET reques using JMeter 3.1, the point is that the path calls a function which has an array as a parameter.

Something like this:

path: /getData(userIds[1,2,3])

The request works well on Fiddler, but it fails on JMeter due to the square brackets characters. Error is *java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path*

Could someone help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try with Java implementation in HTTP request?

Comment: It worked!! Thank you so much!

Comment: I have posted the answer. Please accept :)

Comment: Done, thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the implementation type to **Java** in the HTTP Request Sampler.